# PDO DB query to HTML

Tags: php, html, pdo

I am trying to echo 3 different queries to the same page but I seem to fail and have to ask the DB three times for the answer to echo, which I think looks poor and can probably be simplified, but this is all very new to me.

Currently I have 3 Bootstrap cards which display different information (all from the same table).

Can this be done with PDO? and neatened up?

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Total Assets</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5>

<?php
// Include config file
require_once "includes/config.php";

// Prepare the select statement
$sql="SELECT * FROM asset_details";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    // Return the number of rows in result set
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    printf("Total Number of Assets %d \n",$rowcount);
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</h5>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Record Asset</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> Total Phones</div>
    <div class="card-body">
            <h5>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","asset_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM asset_details WHERE type = 2";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    // Return the number of rows in result set
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    printf("Total Number of phones %d \n",$rowcount);
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Total Laptops</div>
    <div class="card-body">
            <h5>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","asset_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM asset_details WHERE type = 1";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    // Return the number of rows in result set
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    printf("Total Number of Laptops %d \n",$rowcount);
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</h5>

    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not thinking I need to call the query 3 times (although they are all different). The first gives the total number, the second gives the number based on a type integer 2, and the third where the type integer is 1. type is a field within the table.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to tidy this up (and ideally bring me up to speed with 2019 by using PDO here and in the config.php)?

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: you can fetch all data to the one query , and split the array to multiarray by providing the type as spliter and you can loop each one in the specific card .

Comment: I think you should take a look at this tutorial: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: 1) Its not necessary to `mysqli_close($con);` if you intend to use the connection again in the script. In fact PHP will close the connection at the end of the script, so you dont need to bother at all

Comment: 2) if you only want to know how many rows there are and not the contents of the rows do a `$sql="SELECT COUNT(1) as tot FROM asset_details";`

Comment: you can "select type, count(*) nb from asset_details" get the result in an array. and the work on this array.